# Cannot access KnownFolders in Windows.Storage for UWP (For Hololens)

Tags: uwp, hololens

I have installed UwpDesktop package as well as System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll from NuGet Package manager in Visual Studio.

[Here is a pic of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjaBO.jpg)

Comment: I'm trying to do the same. I can't build when I add the `<uap:Capability Name="documentsLibrary"/>` to the appx manifest. Can you share yours? And in the comment to the answer you mention you did it in Unity's publishing settings as well, I don't see Documents Library as an option in Unity or GUI mode of package.appxmanifest. I have to manually add the XML. How did you do that in Unity?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to declare a capability to access the KnownFolder you care about in your appxmanifest. For example, accessing the documents directory would require the following capability in your manifest:

`<Capabilities><uap:Capability Name="documentsLibrary"/></Capabilities>`

For more information, see here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations

Comment: Thanks for the info but i have made the capabilities done inside unity's publishing settings. and confirmed them inside the appxmanifest after the build. i think i am missing something else.

Comment: Oh, this looks like a Unity + WSA issue. You may need to declare these lines behind a "#if WINDOWS_UWP" ifdef because they are [platform specific calls](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html). I don't think that the Unity C# project will be able to resolve these SDKs, but when you compile with IL2CPP or .NET for UWP, things should get picked up correctly.

Comment: You may also be able to use [C# System.IO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.8) calls for this if you need something that works in the editor.